# npm doesn't install my packages on my server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp, polymer-starter-kit

I've a problem getting my app running on my server that runs on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I've developed a javascript app using the polymer framework and it works fine on my linux VM.

But when I pull it from my repo to my server and try to `npm install` modules, it doesn't work. npm does install some strange files in `node_modules/.staging` but I don't get my modules installed.

My version of **node** is:

`$ node -v
v4.1.0`

My version of **npm** is:

`$ npm-v
3.3.3`

I used the `package.json` file from the polymer starter kit: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/package.json

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.7.7",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.6",
    "gulp": "^3.8.5",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.8",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.6.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp-size": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-vulcanize": "^6.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.7",
    "polybuild": "^1.0.5",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "vulcanize": ">= 1.4.2",
    "web-component-tester": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test:local",
    "start": "gulp serve"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to install only devDependencies but it didn't work either.

My server is hosted on Digital Ocean (I don't think the information is relevant though).

*edit: i downgraded my version to 2.14.3 and packages are now correctly installed. However I've a serie of dependencies missing:*

`Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'`

I install it:

`Error: Cannot find module 'sigmund'`

Comment: You may mean this by "I tried to install only devDependencies", but have you run `npm install-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but shouldn't you use bower (or any other tool) to install client side dependencies? I thought npm was intentended to server side packages only.

I used this command to install polymer:

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.1.0
```

Comment: AFAIK, bower is for the elements (like iron-ajax for example). npm is for node_modules dependencies. I try to run gulp here to create a server for the app so I need all my node_modules dependencies.